# Angular 2: Can we create the Form from FormGroup?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am developing a dynamic form where the form elements are modified as per user inputs. Is it possible to generate the complete form by just supplying the FormGroup object to the `<form></form>` tag instead of manually creating each element which is present in the form group.

For Example:

Component.ts

```
fb: FormBuilder;
formGroupData: FormGroup;

constructor() {
this.formGroupData= this.fb.group({
            selectedItem: ['', Validators.required],
            selectedAmount: ['', Validators.required]
        });
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroupData"></form>
```

This should create the entire form without adding the element selectedAmount and selectedItem elements. Is this possible? If not why what's the harm here?

Comment: How do you know what type of input will be created for each of `FormControl` ?

Comment: So that could have been included as the FormGroup Element attribute. In a very similar way the validations were baked into it. right?

Answer (score 0):

They did not build forms to work like that. It would make css challenging especially when adding `<label>`s, input prefixes and suffixes, and other view-side stuff. Ultimately the goal was to separate the view and the model in this way.

You might be able to create a directive like this using the [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html) class if you need to access the view-side stuff.

Comment: but what I feel is that this could have been included in ReactiveFormsModule. This would reduce the development time considerably for people looking for vanilla HTML forms